# Create image with imagepng() (fails at header)

Tags: theme-development, images

I've been struggling with some code for a custom theme.

**The result:**
Create an image with text.

**The problem:**
Fails at header: `code` on production.

The funny thing is that the function works perfectly fine locally, but when I upload everything to production it fails.

The code:

```
$euro = get_option('euro');
$super = get_option('super');
$diesel = get_option('diesel');
$autogas = get_option('autogas');

// create array for prices
$arrayPrice = array(
  0 =>  $euro,
  1 =>  $super,
  2 => $diesel,
  3 => $autogas
);

// Create array for fuels
$arrayFuels = array(
  0 => 'euro',
  1 => 'super',
  2 => 'diesel',
  3 => 'autogas'
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayPrice); $i++) {
  // Set the content-type
  header('Content-Type: image/png');

  // Create the image
  $im = imagecreatetruecolor(105, 27);

  // Create some colors
  $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
  $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
  imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

  // The text to draw
  $text = $arrayPrice[$i];
  // Replace path by your own font path
  $font = ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/gulf-venlo/ledboard.ttf';

  // Add the text
  imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 0, 27, $black, $font, $text);

  // Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
  ob_start();
  imagepng($im);
  $data = ob_get_clean();
  file_put_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/gulf-venlo/img/'.$arrayFuels[$i].'.png', $data);
  imagedestroy($im);
}
```

I've tried various techniques, like:

- Put the function on it's own page and include/require it
- Use more OB functions (start, destroy, get_clean)

#### Local result

The result on my local environment is exactly what it is supposed to be: I put in some prices for every type of fuel, save the changes. After that every image on the website's homepage will be updated to it's new price.

#### Online result

When I choose to edit the prices, I click 'Fuel' in my custom menu only to find a blank page  with a blue rectangle and a question mark (see: http://goo.gl/fwxJXo)

#### Other

I know the code needs some work, as I'm sure there's a better way to save the images to a folder within the theme.

## Solved (edit: May 7, 2015)

A while ago I deleted `header('Content-Type: image/png');` and it magically works. I used to use comments (`//header('Content-Type: image/png');`) to disable it, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: For better help, could you explain exactly where / how it fails? That is a bit unclear in your post. That being said, this sounds like a server configuration issue (e.g. your server does not have the php gd library installed) Check http://php.net/manual/en/image.requirements.php for requirements on using the image funtions.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, instead of an edit. It's OK to [answer your own question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved (edit: May 7, 2015)

A while ago I deleted `header('Content-Type: image/png');` and it magically works. I used to use comments (`//header('Content-Type: image/png');`) to disable it, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `get_template_directory()` instead of `ABSPATH`. If wp-content is not in it's original location on production server that might solve your problem.

Mind the lack of trailing slash after `get_template_directory()`:

```
$font = get_template_directory().'/ledboard.ttf';
...
file_put_contents(get_template_directory().'/img/'.$arrayFuels[$i].'.png', $data);
```

Comment: Thank you, IlmarsL, for your reply. Unfortunately it hasn't solved my issue.